# Why is PyAudio throwing a ModuleNotFoundError when I have it installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I've seen similar questions on this site, but none of the solutions have worked. I am using a mac, which gave me some trouble downloading pyaudio. Eventually, I got pyaudio downloaded using pip3 and portaudio installed with homebrew.

I'm coding a virtual assistant, and when I try to use the speech_recognition module, it throws and error telling me that the module cannot find the pyaudio module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'
```

Yet when I try to run the command `pip3 install pyaudio`, it tells me that pyaudio is already installed:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyaudio in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.2.11)
```

How do I fix this? Do I need to somehow move my pyaudio install into another directory? I don't know if this is related, but I've also noticed that whenever I run a terminal command beginning with python3 I get the error zsh: killed python3. I've downloaded python3 and that's what I've been using, as well as using pip3 instead of pip.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the interpreter that you are using might be different, it happened with me once but with a different package, I installed it in a different env and tried to run it in the different env. First make sure that you have activated your virtual enviornment, and there do a `pip3 list` and check if it shows installed, if it is installed, check the interpreter you are using to run the script, if it's from that `venv` or not.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that should help in any case is to execute `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages` in the shell before you start the Python interpreter.